# Why is A => String not the same as _1.type => String where val _1: A?

Tags: scala, generics, type-members

In this Scala 2.13 example:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object Main2 extends App {

  trait Foo {
    type F = this.type => String
  }

  def fooA[A <: Foo](f: A#F, toString: A#F => String): String = toString(f)
  def fooB[A <: Foo](f: A#F, toString: (A => String) => String): String = toString(f)
}
```

It fails with:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : _1.type => String where val _1: A
 required: A => String
  def fooB[A <: Foo](f: A#F, toString: (A => String) => String): String = toString(f)
```

Why is `A => String` not the same as `_1.type => String where val _1: A`?

Is it safe to cast `f.asInstanceOf[(A => String)]`?

Is there a concrete example where this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstanding what is `this.type`. From [scala 2.13 spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#singleton-types):

> Every value in Scala has a type which is of one of the following forms.
> A singleton type is of the form
> p
> .
> p.type. Where
> p
> p is a path pointing to a value which conforms to scala.AnyRef, the type denotes the set of values consisting of null and the value denoted by
> p
> p (i.e., the value
> v
> v for which v eq p)

It means, that `this.type` will be uniq for each instance of `Foo`. In `fooB`:

```scala
def fooB[A <: Foo](f: A#F, toString: (A => String) => String): String = toString(f)
```

compiler sees that you tries to pass `f` which type is:

```scala
(some object of A which upper-bouned by Foo).type => String
```

function from `singleton-type object` to `String` into *function* what takes function from object of type `A` into `String`.

**Note** object of type `A` (`new A()`) has not the same type as `(new A()).type`, they have different types and this is the reason why compiler shows you an error.

for example, you can write something like that and it will compiles:

```scala
class Bar extends Foo {
  def conversion: this.type => String = b => "bar"
}
def someStringConversion[A <: Foo]: A#F => String = ???
val bar: Bar = new Bar
someStringConversion[Bar](bar.conversion)
val conversionType: bar.type => String = bar.conversion
val customConversion: bar.type => String = (x: bar.type) => "some string"
someStringConversion[Bar](customConversion)
```

because of `bar.type` has the same type as `this.type` (they are both refer into one singleton type - `bar.type`

### Conclusion

Your functions `fooA` and `fooB` have different signatures, `A#F => String` is not the same as `A => String` and you can't use `asInstanceOf` on first. `fooB` will not work on any instance of `Foo` because any `Foo` instance has it's own `this.type` singleton type. It doesn't relate to `Foo` like some `Foo` implementation relates to `Foo`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was misunderstanding what `this.type` was. I don't suppose you have an answer to the original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719303/why-is-this-requiring-an-existential-type-that-is-expanding-to-include-singleton?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a `This` type. Like `this.getClass` but at the type level.

Answer (score 2):

A concrete example where it doesn't work:

```
def fooB[A <: Foo](f: A#F, toString: (A => String) => String): String = ???

trait X extends Foo
trait Y extends Foo

def ok(f: X#F, toString: (Y => String) => String) = fooB(f, toString)
```

This compiles because the compiler resolves the type parameters `A` to be `Foo`. But `f` is clearly not a valid argument for `toString`.